# Dynamic loading of CSS with sequence and priority

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, liferay

I am using LifeRay.

Have some css files in the header section coming thru LifeRay header template (common for all portlets),
and another css file in a portlet (specific to one portlet).

The portlet code is inside portlet - view.JSP.

The generated HTML output is like:

```
<html..>
<head>
...
...
<link href="base.css" ../>
<link id="custom" href="custom.css" />
...
...
</head>
<body>
...
...
<div class='portlet...'>
...
...
<link href="port.css" ../>

..
...
</div>

..
..

</body>
</html>
```

Here, problem is I wanted to have "custom.css" to be loaded at last, but due to liferay structure port.css is getting loaded in the last, after liferay-header template.

One solution is, I can simply have the custom.css inclusion near the bottom of the liferay template (or say, footer template), so that it'll be loaded last (after portlet's port.css), but it's against W3C recommendation - to have all CSS in head section.

Now, I wrote a little script in my portlet .jsp, that will dynamically load the port.css before custom.css, using jquery.

portlet -- view.jsp --

```
$("<link href='port.css' ../>").insertBefore( $("#custom") );
```

..
..

Now, with this approach, in FireBug, I can see the port.css listed "before" custom.css - as expected.
I even observed the styles are applied with proper sequence/priority from both the css.

My queries are:
- How good/correct is this approach?
- Is there any limitation/constraint to this?
- Any Browser issue??

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think this is an awesome approach!

Comment: Why would you need to load it in last? Cannot you just change CSS rules to modify priority?

Comment: @A.Wolff ...because, in my case, port.css - is not just a single css file, and it could be coming from some library/framework - say bootsrap.css! And I need to override some rules thru my custom.css!

Hope this make sense!

Comment: @VijayWadnere But so in custom.css, write more detailed CSS rules to get highest priority, e.g prefixing them using `html body ...`. I meant something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/uxefx9oj/

Comment: This is correct. Only issue is that when you load a CSS via JavaScript it might cause the browser to repaint the document (e.g. when stylesheet specifies a different font on the *body*).

Comment: I forgot, what about using `@import` ?

Comment: i have same problem, i have a bootstrap css used at base and a custom css that overrides some class or some class's attributes. without any priority setting like !important, if i see the page all in one file the order is respected, the last class wins, if i separate a jsp in more pieces (the order of import is the same) the first css declared wins on the second. i will try your solution.